# Defining a chained ruby method definition similar to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am studying the Rails documentation.  Within the [associations documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) they specify method definitions with a chain on them, like this:

> Project#portfolio.nil?

This seemed odd to me.  It would appear that there is an instance method definition that has a chained method on it.  For example: It appears that`Project#portfolio.nil?` would define an instance method that would look like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def portfolio.nil?
    ...
  end
end
```

I have never seen instance methods defined like this before: where a chain is specified within the actual instance method definition.  I attempted to replicate it with straight ruby and I couldn't get it to work.

```
class Dog
  def speak
   puts "woof woof"
  end

  def speak.fetch
    puts "go get the ball!"
  end
end
```

However this does not work.  There is a `NameError`

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `speak' for Dog:Class

If it did work: then I would try `Dog.new.speak.fetch`.  I am not sure what it would return.  Maybe it would return:

```
=> woof woof!
=> go get the ball!
```

**Question**: Is it even possible to somehow define instance method definitions with chains on them like this?  If not: how does rails do it?  Using `Project#portfolio.nil?` as an example: how does Rails go about defining `#portfolio.nil?` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a bug (or, let's call it a slightly misleading wording) in the Rails documentation. To quote from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html :

> The project class now has the following methods (and more) to ease the traversal and manipulation of its relationships:
>   `Project#portfolio, Project#portfolio=(portfolio), Project#portfolio.nil?`

The third entry in that list is obviously just a hint that `nil` is a valid value of the relationship attribute.

(And the answer to the question is "no", you cannot define a chain of methods in Ruby in one `def`.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with one fundamental thing:

> In Ruby, there are no primitives. Everything is objects. All have one
>   common ancestor, the Object class.

So when you use `dot notation`, you call method from object.

When you use `nil?` it means that you call method which checks that the `object` is equal to nil. You can call this method from any object:

```
Object.nil? # => false
```

In your code you have `Project` model which has associations `Portofolio`.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :portfolio
end
```

Documentation says:

> Belongs_to: Specifies a one-to-one association with another class.
>
> Methods will be added for retrieval and query for a single associated
>   object, for which this object holds an id: association is a
>   placeholder for the symbol passed as the name argument, so belongs_to
>   :author would add among others author.nil?.

For example:

```
project = Project.first
# this will get portfolio from database by foreign key
puts project.portfolio  
# You can check that there is no records in database
puts project.portfolio.nil?
```

Closing words: when you call any method, you call it from some object.

Comment: What I think he means is that documentation lists `Project#portfolio.nil?` as a __separate method__. This is confusing. How can this be one method name?

Comment: Yes: as mentioned: how can portfolio.nil? be one method name?